# using ActionListener into another ActionListener

Tags: java, actionlistener

I want to use the first ActionListener (About) into the second ActionListener (About2)
without copying the first one into teh second one are there any way to do that?

```
About.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        @Override
       public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){
          AboutMe.setLocation(470,250);
          AboutMe.setSize(400, 200);
          AboutMe.setVisible(true);
          AboutMe.setResizable(false);
          AboutMe.add(panel5);
          panel5.setLayout(null);
          panel5.add(ta);

         ta.setBounds(15, 15, 350, 130);
         ta.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder());
         ta.setText("...................................\n"
                 +  "....................................\n"
                 +  "....................................\n"
                 +  "....................................\n"
                 +  "....................................");
         ta.setEditable(false);
       }
       }
   );



About2.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        @Override
       public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){

                  ////////code here///////////////
       }
       }
   );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well as long as you're not using the `ActionEvent` argument, you could just create a method like this in your class,

```
public void doAction() {
 AboutMe.setLocation(470,250);
          AboutMe.setSize(400, 200);
          AboutMe.setVisible(true);
          AboutMe.setResizable(false);
          AboutMe.add(panel5);
          panel5.setLayout(null);
          panel5.add(ta);

         ta.setBounds(15, 15, 350, 130);
         ta.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder());
         ta.setText("...................................\n"
                 +  "....................................\n"
                 +  "....................................\n"
                 +  "....................................\n"
                 +  "....................................");
         ta.setEditable(false);
}
```

and in your `actionPerformed` methods, just call

```
doAction();
```

So like this,

```
About.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        @Override
       public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){
doAction();

   );
```

Answer (score 2):

The simplest thing to do here would be to copy the reference of that anonymous object into a temp variable and pass that reference.

```
ActionListener temp= new ActionListener(){
        @Override
       public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){
          AboutMe.setLocation(470,250);
          AboutMe.setSize(400, 200);
          AboutMe.setVisible(true);
          AboutMe.setResizable(false);
          AboutMe.add(panel5);
          panel5.setLayout(null);
          panel5.add(ta);

         ta.setBounds(15, 15, 350, 130);
         ta.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder());
         ta.setText("...................................\n"
                 +  "....................................\n"
                 +  "....................................\n"
                 +  "....................................\n"
                 +  "....................................");
         ta.setEditable(false);
       }
       };

About.AddActionListener(temp);
About2.AddActionListener(temp);
```

Another option would be to make your class implement ActionListener and simply do:

```
About.AddActionListener(this)
About2.AddActionListener(this);
```

While you can do the above as stated in the comment it isn't the best idea. 
Another option is create another class to implement ActionListener and create an instance of that class.

```
public class ReusableListener implements ActionListener

ActionListener listener = new ReusableListener() ;//as a field

About.addActionListener(listener) ;
About2.addActionListener(listener) ;
```

Comment: I like the answer apart from the part about having the class itself implement ActionListener, having maintained classes that extends JFrame implements ActionListener, MouseListener, MouseMotionListener, DocumentListener....

Comment: @RickyClarkson I understand. I wouldn't recommend it either. I will edit my answer.